# How to shut down Linux if idle for 30+ minutes?

Tags: startup, shutdown

We define "idle" based on how screen savers in Linux define it.

I found this tool called "xautolock".

I tested it like this:

```
/usr/X11R6/bin/xautolock -time 1 -locker "notify-send test"
```

I placed this in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, but for some reason it was not working and I couldn't debug it.

Someone said to place it in `.bash_profile`. I found this file and placed it in there, but now my GUI won't start.

Because this command is a forever command, it always listens once executed. It never stops listening in order to determine idleness, so this means it can not go into `.bash_profile`.

I do not know how to place it in to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, so where can it go if it can not go into these files?

Perhaps there is a way to modify it so it can go into `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`? Perhaps something like:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/X11R6/bin/xautolock -time 1 -locker "notify-send test"
```

Would that work?

I'm on CentOS and GNOME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't place it in `rc.local` because it will require a running X session and `rc.local` is usually executed before or during starting X. Also the `DISPLAY` variable would have to be set as you already figured out correctly.

If you want to place it in your `.bash_profile` then just put a `&` at the end to run it in the background.